# Argument mismatch in SecureZeroMemory in C++

Tags: visual-c++

```
char *chBuff = new char[nBufferSize];
    ::SecureZeroMemory(chBuff, sizeof(chBuff));
```

I used the above code but get the following error

```
Wrong sizeof argument (SIZEOF_MISMATCH)
suspicious_sizeof: Passing argument chBuff of type char * and argument 4UL /* sizeof (chBuff) */ to function RtlSecureZeroMemory is suspicious.
```

Should I typecast? If so how?

syntax of SecureZeroMemory:

```
PVOID SecureZeroMemory(
  _In_  PVOID ptr,
  _In_  SIZE_T cnt
);
```

Comment: You want to pass the size of the buffer, not the size of the pointer to the buffer. If `chBuff < sizeof(char*)`, you just introduced a buffer overflow, which may be exploitable as a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(char *) will provide you size of a pointer, instead, use the following:

```
char *chBuff = new char[nBufferSize];
    ::SecureZeroMemory(chBuff, sizeof(char)*nBufferSize);
```